# "list index out of range" when try to output lines from a text file using python

Tags: python, list, file-io, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception

I was trying to extract even lines from a text file and output to a new file. But with my codes python warns me "list index out of range". Anyone can help me? THANKS~

Code:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
i = 0
j = 0 
num_lines = sum(1 for line in f)
newline = [0] * num_lines
print (num_lines)
for i in range(1, num_lines):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        newline[i] = f.readlines()[i]
            print i, newline[i]
    i = i + 1
f.close()
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
for j in range(0,num_lines):
    if j % 2 == 0:
        f.write(newline[j] + '\n')
    j = j + 1
f.close()
```

Output:

```
17
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./5", line 10, in <module>
    a = f.readlines()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 3):

After

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in f)
```

The file pointer in `f` is *at the end of the file*. Therefore any subsequent call of `f.readlines()` gives an empty list. The minimal fix is to use [`f.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to return to the start of the file.

However, a better solution would be to read through the file only once, e.g. using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the `line` and its index `i`:

```
newline = []
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        newline.append(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your original script you read the file once to scan the number of lines, then you (try to) read the lines in memory, you needlessly create a list for the full size instead of just extending it with `list.append`, you initialize the list with zeroes which does not make sense for a list containing strings, etc.

Thus, this script does what your original idea was, but better and simpler and faster:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as inf, open('output.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(inf, 1):
        if lineno % 2 == 0:
            outf.write(line)
```

Specifically

- open the files with with statement so that they are automatically closed when
   the block is exited.
- write as they are read
- as lines are numbered 1-based, use the enumerate with the start value 1 so that you truly get the even numbered lines.

Answer (score 3):

You've also got the `itertools.islice` approach available:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(islice(fin, None, None, 2))
```

This saves the modulus operation and puts the line writing to system level.

Comment: JonClements - improving on the very best :D