# search a file for a string and print relevant line from the file

Tags: python, string, file, search

I have two files. One (e-number.txt) that contains a long species list and some info on every species and one (artsliste.txt) that contains species from a certain location.
I want to extract the info in e-number.txt for all the species listed in artsliste.txt.
Print the corresponding line to be short.

I feel like I am close, and feel like it can't be too hard, but I might have started out all wrong.

The latest code I have:

```
ellenberg=open('e-number.txt').read()
arter=open('artsliste.txt','r')

for line in arter:
    art = arter.readline()
    if art in ellenberg:
        print(ellenberg)
```

artsliste.txt contains stuff like this:

> Acer pseudoplatanus
>
> Acer platanoides
>
> Aeculus hippocastaneum
>
> Adoxa moschatellina
>
> Sambucus nigra
>
> Aegopodium podagraria
>
> Anthriscus sylvestris

e-number.txt contains stuff like this:

> Acaena    novae-zelandiae 2527    .   8   .   3   .   6   .   3   .   0   Acae nova   Acaena novae-zelandiae
>
> Acer  campestre   3   5   5   5   5   7   7   6   6   0   0   Acer camp   Acer campestre
>
> Acer  platanoides 4   4   4   .   5   .   7   .   7   0   0   Acer plat   Acer platanoides
>
> Acer  pseudoplatanus  5   4   4   6   5   .   6   7   6   0   0   Acer pseu   Acer pseudoplatanus

I would like my output to look like:

> Acer  pseudoplatanus  5   4   4   6   5   .   6   7   6   0   0   Acer pseu   Acer pseudoplatanus
>
> Oenanthe   crocata 1363    .   7   .   8   .   6   .   7   .   1       Oenanthe crocata
>
> Trifolium  medium  2087    7   7   4   4   6   6   3   4   0   0       Trifolium medium

I feel like there most be a function that can print the line that was found, either way i guess i have to setup another search function inside the one i have already and that doesnt make any sense.
Hope someone can get me in the right direction.
Best regards.

Comment: How large are your files? Can they be held in memory? Can you show a few lines from your input files and the desired output?

Comment: `for lineno, line in enumerate(filehandle)`?

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry. Enumber is 100kb. Artsliste is 20kb.

Comment: You should read the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24752426/3001761). Also, you should clarify what this question's question is - this isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

From the [readline](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) documentation:

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character
>   (\n) is left at the end of the string

```
art = arter.readline().strip()
```

should help.

UPDATED according to your comment

Try this:

```
for line in arter:
    art = arter.readline().strip()
    index = ellenberg.find(art)
    if index > -1:
        line_end_index = ellenberg.find('\n', index)
        print(ellenberg[index:line_end_index])
```

ONE MORE UPDATE:
This code will print full relevant line only if line starts with `art` else it will print chunk from entry point of `art` to the end of line.

To print full line you could use following code:

```
ellenberg=open('e-number.txt').readlines()
arter=open('artsliste.txt','r')
for line in arter:
    for ellenberg_line in ellenberg:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0 and line.strip() in ellenberg_line:
          print ellenberg_line
```

Comment: Thanks, that part works. Thing is the line should be from the other file.

Comment: It is a leap forward. I edited it to print(ellenberg[index-22:line_end_index]) to get the whole line, not the best way, but it works for now. Will continue later. thanks.

Comment: it gets me the numbers in front of the species name though its not pretty.